# Workflow core Action "Send an Email" for approval task

Tags: 2013, workflow-activity

I am trying to use "Send an Email" work flow action to notify the approver for his approval with, Email has to contain the URL to the approval page.

I am trying to create a leave request form.

project contains 2 list 
       1) Leave request
       2) Workflow Task (sharepoint 2013)

I am starting the workflow using the "Create Item" and using the "content TypeID"-Workflow Task(Sharepoint 2013) to get the approve and reject on the task approval page.

[image]

I am use the lookup field in workflow task(sharepoint 2013) to lookup a field in the "leave Request field called "ID" to get a relation between 2 list.

Once i created the task, i want to send email notification to approver, which should contain the link to the site where he can approve or reject

i tried most possibility, unable to correct URL in the EMAIL 
this is 2 stage approval process. once manager approves and then another task is created and another email is send to the HR with the correct link.

please help me on how to select the correct URL .

Comment: Is there a reason you're not utilizing the Approval action for this workflow?

Comment: Hi i have resolved it.